# VS 2012: RouteTable.Routes.Add doesn't work?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, rest, visual-studio-2012

I have a WCF REST service project in VS 2010 where I change RouteTable at application startup adding a route:

RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("AppServer", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MyService)));

It worked in vs 2010 and when running in in development server I could call methods from a browser like:

```
http://localhost:12345/AppServer/MyMethod
```

Then I installed VS 2012, converted the project, it compiles perfectly but I can't access methods via AppServer route anymore. It just says "The resource cannot be found.".

I checked the service, the line which adds the route is still called.

Any ideas what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a pb in configuration, closing.